# EMR pyspark trackable logging architecture

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, amazon-emr

I am in middle of building a pyspark application that fails alot and has lot of jobs with lot of steps, so it is not possible to search with `cluster id` and `step id`. the current format in which spark on emr save is below

```
S3/buckt-name/logs/sparksteps/j-{clusterid}/steps/s-{stepid}/stderr.gz
```

I want something traceable in place of `{clusterid}` and `{stepid}` such that `clustername+datetime` and `step-name`

I saw log4j.properties and it has something named datepattern, but it is not saving anything with datetime

Answer (score 0):

You could index the logs into an ELK cluster (managed or not) using filebeats.

Or send the logs to cloudwatch logs using a bootstrap script on the EMR or a Lambda. You can then customize the log group and log stream names to your needs.